# Setup web server when using selenium webdriver c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, selenium, bdd

Im using selenium webdriver to make behavior tests on ASP.NET MVC application (C#).
I want to have a server that will automatically open when I run those tests, like the IIS server which automatically runs when I debug my application.
How do I do that ?
BTW, Im using the ChromeDriver if that matters.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen Stephen Walther's post which explains how you can create integration tests for ASP.NET MVC applications by using a combination of Selenium WebDriver and IISExpress?

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2011/12/22/asp-net-mvc-selenium-iisexpress.aspx